# Remove weird characters using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string `â€˜Some string hereâ€™`. I want to remove these weird characters(â€˜, â€™) from this string. I am currently using `replace()` function but it does not replace it with empty string. Below is the script. How can I remove it?

```
  for (var i = 0, len = el.length; i < len; i++) {
      $(el[i]).text().replace("â€˜", "");
  }
```

Comment: Depending on your context and how many characters you want to replace. Would it not be easier to define allowed characters, and remove any that you didn't specify?

Comment: The problem is that these strings are generated automatically using some kind of software. I need to remove them using javascript

Answer (score 5):

you have to just remove the elements whose ascii value is less then 127

```
var input="â€˜Some string hereâ€™.";
var output = "";
    for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        if (input.charCodeAt(i) <= 127) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
 alert(output);//Some string here.
```

[**fiddle link**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ktm4U/)

**OR**

remove your loop and try

```
$(el[i]).text().replace("â€˜","").replace("â€™","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Those weird characters probably aren't so weird; they're most likely a symptom of a [character encoding problem](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). At a guess, they're [smart quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_electronic_documents) that aren't showing up correctly.

Rather than try to strip them out of your text, you should update your page so it displays as UTF-8. Add this in your page header:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

---

So why does this happen? Basically, most character encodings are the same for "simple" text - letters, numbers, some symbols - but have different representations for less common characters (accents, other alphabets, less common symbols, etc). When your browser gets a document without any indication of its character encoding, the browser will make a guess. Sometimes it gets it wrong, and you see weird characters like â€˜ instead of what you expected.

Comment: I added that meta tag in the head using javascript but it still shows these weird(for me) characters.

Comment: Don't add it via JavaScript; I don't think a browser will re-interpret the page if you add the tag after the page is loaded. You should hard-code it into your HTML.

Comment: HTML is not in my hand in this scenario. It is generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me:

```
"â€˜Some string hereâ€™".replace("â€˜","").replace("â€™","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HN2cT/) for your problem solution

Code Snippet:

```
var str = "â€˜Some string hereâ€";
str = str.replace("â€˜", "");
str = str.replace("â€", "");
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.filter('SpecialCharacterToSingleQuote', function() {
        return function(text) {
            return text ? String(text).replace(/â/g, "'").replace(/&#128;|&#153;|&#156;|&#157;/g, "") : '';
        };
    });
```