# How do I convert the misinterpreted UTF-8 instances in my string, e.g. â€™, to their proper characters?

Tags: javascript, string, text, unicode, utf-8

I have a string which includes many instances of misinterpreted UTF/unicode characters, such as â€™ instead of an apostrophe. Is there any way I can manipulate the entire string and create a new string, with all the misinterpreted characters replaced by their proper counterparts?

e.g. instead of

```
var string = "This personâ€™s something...."
```

I want

```
var fixedstring = "This person's something...."
```

Comment: The question might be a bit older but the solution is probably still working as you would like: Here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629467/remove-weird-characters-using-jquery-javascript>

Comment: Yes, there are ways, but really you should fix the part of the code that messes up the string in the first place.

Comment: "*replaced by their proper counterparts*". Not just removed.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. The thing is, the content of the string is just copy-pasted from a .txt file which I converted from a pdf. The weird characters appeared in the .txt file already. Which is why, rather than combing through the txt file, I want to just manipulate the string.

Comment: Or you can use the solution and just add the thing that is missing. $(el[i]).text().replace("â€˜","XX").replace("â€™","YY"); It seems like the encoding is the problem and that is like hard to correct.

Comment: How did you convert the pdf and save to the txt file? How did you open the txt file?

Comment: I used an online converter, pdftotext.com. I downloaded the .txt file, copied its contents, used a line-break-remover tool, then pasted that between the quotes in `var string = " "`

Comment: When you "copied the contents", were they already broken? Either pdftotext.com, your file viewer, or the line-break-remover tool had an encoding issue.

Comment: If telling the file viewer to use a different encoding doesn't solve the problem, try running [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)

Comment: Yes, the contents I copied were already broken. I don't know if that online converter supports using alternate encoding.

Comment: @HelloWorld First thing you need to do is validate whether the PDF converter outputs a properly formatted TXT file or not. View the TXT file in a hex editor to check whether its bytes are properly encoded UTF-8. If not valid UTF-8, use a different PDF converter that outputs UTF-8 properly. If valid UTF-8, then your TXT viewer is misinterpreting the encoding, so change the encoding the viewer uses to process the file, or else use a different viewer that doesn't misinterpret.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've actually found a roundabout solution. After doing some research, I learned that the strange character interpretations, i.e. â€™, are the Windows-1252 equivalents of apostrophes and such. I used this site: http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx to translate my string as Windows-1252 and decode it in utf-8. The output had all the interpretations fixed with their proper apostrophe characters.